# allure-behave : The term 'allure-behave' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: python, automation, allure, python-behave

I created new (virt_env) and installed allure-behave by using command: `pip install allure-behave`.

To verify it installed I use `pip list` command:
[image]

When I run my automation tests I see allure-results folder with JSON files:
[image]

But when I'm trying to generate report by running command `allure generate` I see error:
allure-behave : The term 'allure-behave' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
[image]

How to fix it?

I followed instructions from [Allure WebSite](https://allurereport.org/docs/behave/)

When I'm trying to run `allure-behave --version` I have same error:
[image]

I'm not sure if it matters but I'm using PowerShell to run commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Allure Commandline to generate the report from the allure results. See https://allurereport.org/docs/gettingstarted-installation/